# mouseleave 2 elements show/hide 1 element?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 elements a `<ul>` and a `<div>`.

If I hover over the div I want the ul to appear and when I mouseleave the div I want to check if the mouse is over the ul, if not I want to hide the ul again.

This is my code it works in Chrome and safari but not in Firefox does anyone know what might cause this bug?

```
$('.footer')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('ul#date').fadeIn();
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        $('ul#date').hover(
            function() {
                $('ul#date').mouseleave(function() {
                    $('.footer').hover(
                        function() {
                            return;
                        },
                        function() {
                            $('ul#date').fadeOut();
                        }
                    );
                });
            },
            function() {
                $('ul#date').fadeOut();
            }
        );
    });
```

**EDIT**
HTML markup

```
<div id="main-wrapper">

    <div class="clearfix" id="main">

        <div class="column" id="content">

            <div class="section">

                <h1 id="page-title" class="title">Titletest</h1>

                <div class="region region-content">

                    <div class="block" id="block-system-main">

                        <div class="content">

                            <div typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" class="node" id="node-13">

                                <ul id="date" style="display: none;">

                                </ul>

                            </div><!-- /.node -->

                        </div>

                    </div><!-- /.block -->

                </div><!-- /.region -->

            </div>

        </div><!-- /.section, /#content -->

    </div>

</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

**SOLUTION**

Ok, thanks to crowicked I came to my desired effect, this is the code for the people who are interested.

```
$('.footer').hover(
    function()
    { 
        $('ul#date').stop();

        if ($('ul#date:hidden'))
        { 
            $('ul#date').fadeIn();
        }

    }
);

$('ul#date').mouseleave( function(){ $('ul#date').fadeOut(); });
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML structure. There are a lot of event handlers being assigned inside event handlers there, and that should really be avoided.

Comment: I agree with Rory ... its a bit Inception-like

Comment: seems like there's nothing between "main-wrapper" and "footer" (except maybe margins/padding). check the answer I gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not enclose the `ul#date` inside the `.footer` element and just use the `.hover()` function on the `.footer` to show/hide the `<ul>`?

**EDIT:**
Added the drupal tag.
Try something like this:

```
$('.footer').hover(
   if ($('ul#date').is(':hidden')) {
      function(){
         $('ul#date').fadeIn();
      }
   }
);

$('ul#date').mouseleave( function(){
   $('ul#date').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I've tried to do this but I'm new to drupal and in drupal the footer is separated from the actual nodes so from what I understand I can't just add the date ul to the footer.

Comment: this is a pretty good solution, I just don't like the flicker this causes when I mouse over in this order: footer > ul#date > footer

Comment: edited: added "if ($('ul#date').is(':hidden')) { function(){ $('ul#date').fadeIn(); }}"

it shouldn't flicker now 'cause it will only fade-in the ul when it's completely hidden.

Comment: Hey thanks crowicked, I got what I wanted with your help. I've added a stop() before the if-statement because the ul#date was already starting to hide. Thank you very much, I've edited my original post with the solution if you want to see.

Comment: Glad you did.
Although, I think your "if" clause is mistyped (and is just slowing you down) - you're missing the ".is()" method. Nevertheless, ".stop()" alone  solved the problem & it works. You can probably even remove the "if" clause completely. Didn't realize there was a "stop()" method at all. I learned something new, too. +1!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be this?

```
$('.footer').mouseenter(function(){     
    $('ul#date').fadeIn();      
}).mouseleave(function(){       
    $('ul#date').hover(function(){          
        $('ul#date').mouseleave(function(){             
            $('.footer').hover(function(){                  
                return;                 
            }, function() {                 
                $('ul#date').fadeOut();             
            });         
        }, function(){          
            $('ul#date').fadeOut();         
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: no because I want a callback function called on the hovers and not on the mouseleaves. I admit it's might be bad coding and even worse formatting of code